# PHPUnit Selenium2 - No Browser Instance

Tags: phpunit, selenium-webdriver

When I run even a sample test, either in Netbeans IDE of from the command line, e.g.:

```
class WebTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{
protected function setUp()
{
    $this->setBrowser('firefox');
    $this->setBrowserUrl('http://www.example.com/');
}

public function testTitle()
{
    $this->url('http://www.example.com/');
    $this->assertEquals('Example WWW Page', $this->title());
}

}
```

I get the PHPUnit response, but it doesn't seem to be communication with the Selenium server as no browser window was created.

```
PHPUnit 3.6.10 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /var/www/gcd/framework/yii/gadget/protected/tests/phpunit.xml

F

Time: 1 second, Memory: 10.50Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) WebTest::testTitle
Failed asserting that null matches expected 'Example WWW Page'.
```

Using PHPUnit 3.6.10 and selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Turns out, if you run PHPUnit with sudo, it works! Doh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, if you run PHPUnit with sudo, it works! Doh!